# What does this mean? ($\boldsymbol{I}_{\theta, \infty}(x_i)$)

Tags: inference, terminology, definition

In my studies I came across this
[image]

There is some more to this answer but for the purpose of this question lets leave it at that.

I can't figure out what $\boldsymbol{I}_{\theta, \infty}(x_i/i)$ is and have already spent way to long trying to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's the Indicator Function on the interval $[\theta, \infty)$

Comment: so $I_{[\theta, \infty)}(x_i/i) = 1$ if $x_i/i \in [\theta, \infty)$ and 0 otherwise?

Comment: exactly! There is nothing more to it than notation